# Adding a category to my own class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, categories

My `AppDelegate` class has quite a few methods. In my attempt to organize these methods I'm trying to group some of these methods in a category.

So now I have these files:

- AppDelegate.h
- AppDelegate.m
- AppDelegate+GameCenter.h
- AppDelegate+GameCenter.m

My category is ofcourse defined like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate (GameCenter)
// methods
@end
```

When I compile I get this error: 'Cannot find interface declaration for 'AppDelegate'.

I think that means I have to import a file somewhere. But what file do I have to import and where? My first thought was to import AppDelegate+GameCenter.h in AppDelegate.m. But that doesn't work. Any tips? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this error is coming from a missing

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

in the header of "AppDelegate+GameCenter.h". Add that, and, of course, stick with

```
#import "AppDelegate+GameCenter.h"
```

in the header of `AppDelegate.m`, as you've done.